# How to make this Java JApplet file work with Command Prompt?

Tags: java, command-prompt

In my textbook, I'm learning to create a simple HappyFace.java program, which outputs a smiley face using JApplet and Graphics methods.

```
import javax.swing.JApplet; // swing library package
import java.awt.Graphics; //Graphics from AWT library

//inheritance used to create HappyFace based on existing class JApplet
public class HappyFace extends JApplet //class definition for applet = HappyFace
{
    //one method = paint
    //Paint method specifies what graphics are drawn in the applet
    public void paint(Graphics canvas)
    {
        //method drawOval or fillOval contains number values (x, y, width, height)
        //units are in pixels
        canvas.drawOval(100,50,200,200); //big circle outline of the face
        canvas.fillOval(155,100,10,20); //eye one
        canvas.fillOval(230,100,10,20); //eye two
        canvas.drawArc(150,160,100,50,180,180); //smile arc on the face (x, y, width, height, StartAngle, ArcAngle)


    }
}
```

I'm struggling to display the output in command prompt however, it delivers this message:

[image]

What should I do differently or what did I do wrong with my code? (I practically wrote exactly as mentioned in the book, but with few comments added)

Do I need to add: `public static void main(String[] args` to the program?

When I use eclipse however and run it, it opens the JApplet and outputs the smiley face.

[image]

I'm assuming that putting the java file into a package in Eclipse somehow makes this work, if this is the case: What is the correct method of having java files work in command prompt?

Any response is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
Following Arvind's advice, I came up with:
[image]

But the smiley face still does not appear after inputting these commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add main():

From cmd/terminal: use command `appletviewer` instead of `java`,

Run command:

```
appletviewer HappyFace.java
```

You need to have applet comment in your source code just above your class definition:

```
/*
<applet code='HappyFace.class' width='200' height='200'></applet>
*/
public class HappyFace extends JApplet {
```

If you do not wish to change you code, then you could also create a html file with same applet code i.e.

*HappyFace.html*

```
<applet code='HappyFace.class' width='200' height='200'></applet>
```

Run command:

```
appletviewer HappyFace.html
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response, I inputted "appletviewer HappyFace.java", and it accepted the command. But nothing happens afterwards, I'm assuming that command initialized the file to be ready for applet use. Is there a second command that opens the applet viewer and shows the smiley face?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I inputted both commands I get a return error "I/O exception while reading: C:\Users\Abdullah\Desktop\java\HappyFace (The system cannot find the file specified)" I changed this to "appletviewer HappyFace.java" but nothing happens still. I've attached an image for reference in the question

Comment: Tried the first method, that works! I didn't know I had to set code for the class file as well, good to know! Thanks again!